# how to calculate numbers in a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, integer, int, parseint

I'm getting some inputs from the user and saving them in a div tag just like a calculator works, for example, a user puts 100-50+30 then I store it in div tag at and when user clicks on go button I want to show him the result which is 80.
I tried parseint and number since string contains operators like + / * these don't work

```
var a = document.querySelector(".output").innerHTML;
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: I think `eval` will work here

Comment: Eval is evil...

Comment: @EliasSoares in general I'd agree, but if the OP's code is *constructing* the expressions then it's not dangerous; the only real alternative is to write an expression parser of one's own.

Comment: If you want to avoid potential code execution, you can use an existing library like [mathjs](https://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `eval()` function

```
var expression = '100-50+30';
console.log(eval(expression));
```

The `eval()` function evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `eval`, but for security reasons I would recommend removing everything from user input except for digits and permitted operators before evaluating the expression:

```js
const input = '100-50+30 [some malicious code]'

const result = eval(input.replace(/[^0-9\+\-\*\/]/g, ''));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: If you want a more robust check e.g. avoid potential error throwing, ensure the format using `/^[+-]?\d+([+/*-]\d+)*$/.test(input)` and do not execute if it returns false. If you want to also handle decimals it will be a bit more complex (and will depend on if you want to support things like `.5` and `1.` as valid numbers)